# Airflow Macros In Python Operator

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to use the Airflow macros in my Python Operator but I keep receiving "airflow: error: unrecognized arguments:"

So I am importing a function that has 3 positional arguments: (*sys.argv,start_date,end_date*) and I am hoping to make the *start_date* and *end_date* the execution date in Airflow.

The function arguments look something like this

```
def main(argv,start_date,end_date):
```

Here is the task I have in the DAG:

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Pull_DCM_Report',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=main,
    op_args=[sys.argv,'{{ ds }}','{{ ds }}'],
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you're passing in dates that need to be rendered by Airflow, you'll want to use the [`templates_dict`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L55) parameter in the Python Operator. This field is the only one that Airflow will recognize as containing templates.

You can create a custom Python operator that recognizes more fields as templates by copy-ing the existing operator and add the relevant fields to the [`template_fields`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L64) tuple.

```py
def main(**kwargs):
    argv = kwargs.get('templates_dict').get('argv')
    start_date = kwargs.get('templates_dict').get('start_date')
    end_date = kwargs.get('templates_dict').get('end_date')


t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='Pull_DCM_Report',
                    provide_context=True,
                    python_callable=main,
                    templates_dict={'argv': sys.argv,
                                    'start_date': '{{ yesterday_ds }}',
                                    'end_date': '{{ ds }}'},
                    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "wrap" the call to the `main` function with the following:

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Pull_DCM_Report',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=lambda **context: main([], context["ds"], context["ds"]),
    dag=dag)
```

If lambdas aren't your cup of tea you could define a function, call that, and have it call out to `main`.